# .htaccess: Unable to catch rule using RewriteCond

Tags: regex, facebook, .htaccess

Facebook returns the following result:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/some-text-here-auth-login.html?session={%22session_key%22%3A%2295da8e65851d8ec74c381171-650901429%22%2C%22uid%22%3A%22650901429%22%2C%22expires%22%3A0%2C%22secret%22%3A%223chidden%22%2C%22base_domain%22%3A%22mydomain.com%22%2C%22access_token%22%3A%22171372936213670|95da8e65851d8ec74c381171-650901429|x_1y78ix4VU8Wr9qytDqV-DWBk0%22%2C%22sig%22%3A%22708bf3fd1703e4c368afe22fc70ed08c%22}
```

On my .htaccess are the following lines:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} session=\{(.*)\}
RewriteRule ^some-text-here-(\w+)-(\w+).html    /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&session=%1 [L]
```

But it's not falling into the rule.

Could you please help a dumber like me figure it out? Thanks!

Comment: OK I've figured it out. the 1st line should be: 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} session=(.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I've figured it out. The 1st line should be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} session=(.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

A better idea than your solution is not to touch the querystring manually at all and instead use QSA to append it to the rewritten URL.

```
RewriteRule ^some-text-here-(\w+)-(\w+).html    /index.php?c=$1&m=$2 [QSA,L]
```